# Understanding the Power Group (a permutation group)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Let $\text{Map}\left(N, R\right)$ denote the set of mappings from the set $N$ to the set $R$. Given permutation groups $G,H$ on the sets $N, R$, respectively, $G$ and $H$ give rise to another permutation group, called the *power group* (on the set $\text{Map}\left(N, R\right)$) given by

$$H^G := \lbrace h^g: g\in G, h\in H\rbrace \tag{power group}$$

where $$h^g \left(f\right) := hfg \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall f\in \text{Map}\left(N, R\right).$$

Further, for finite sets $N, R$, with $\lvert R \rvert >1$, the order of $H^G$ is $\lvert H\rvert \lvert G \rvert$, whereas the cardinality of $\text{Map}\left(N, R\right)$ is $\lvert R \rvert ^{\lvert N \rvert}$.

I need assistance with the definition/notation of the power group $H^G$ since my current understanding of it leads me to the false conclusion that $\text{Map}\left(N, R\right)$ always has cardinality $1$.

**Example.** Let $G$ and $H$ be singletons (groups) consisting of the identity permutations on $N, R$, respectively. Define $e_G, e_H$ to be the identity elements of $G, H,$ respectively. Consider $h=e_H, g=e_G$. For any $f\in \text{Map}\left(N, R\right)$, we have
$$h^g\left(f\right)=e_Hfe_G=f,$$
(since for any $x\in N$, we have $e_Hfe_G(x)=e_H f(x)=f(x)$) and this implies $H^G=\text{Map}\left(N,R\right)$. However, this would imply

$$\lvert \text{Map}\left(N, R\right)\rvert=\lvert H^G \rvert= \lvert H \rvert \lvert G \rvert=1$$ for *any* sets $N, R$.

Comment: What makes you think that $H^G=\text {Map}(N,R)$?   $H,G$ are defined with minimal reference to $N$ and $R$....unless you meant to say that these were the full permutations on their respective sets (but in that case you can't also require that they be singletons without similarly restricting $N,R$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only considered one element $h^g$ of $H^G$, namely the one where $h$ and $g$ are the neutral elements of the respective groups. Also, you verified that this (one) element if $H^G$ acts as the identity on $\operatorname{Map}(N,R)$, so is apparently the neutral element of the group $H^G$. Ultimately, we certainly do *not* have $H^G=\operatorname{Map}(B,R)$ *ever* because elements of $H^G$ are maps from $\operatorname{Map}(N,R)$ to itself and not maps from $N$ to $R$.